# Bash "unexpected end of file" on line 11, there is no line 11

Tags: bash

I'm trying a new conky theme on my Lubuntu system, and for running it I need to start a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#sleep 18&&
conky -c /home/mathijs/conky/conky1&&
sleep 1&&
conky -c /home/mathijs/conky/conky2&&
sleep 1&&
conky -c /home/mathijs/conky/conky3&&
sleep 1&&
conky -c /home/mathijs/conky/conkyxx&&
sleep 1&&
```

When I run the script, the terminal gives me this error:

```
./start.sh: line 11: syntaxerror: unexpected end of file
```

Yet in the script there are only 10 lines. I rewrote it by hand, and checked again, but got the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: And what is the point of adding `&&` after `sleep 1`. This command is always successful.

Comment: One of my first bash scripts, downloaded it as-is!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell metacharacter `&&` expects a command afterwards, that would be run if the first command succeeds.

Thats why you are getting the error message.

For example you have `sleep 1&&` at the 10th line, now the shell will run `sleep 1` and then if it succeeds (exit code 0) then (`&&`) will run the next command, which is not provided by you. So you would get a `unexpected end of file` error message.

Also i think you meant to use `&` instead of `&&`.

`&` will take a foreground process to the background so you can do some other stuffs on the foreground. Also that might no be a good idea with `sleep` command (depends on use case though) as `sleep` intends to pause the execution of command in the script or the terminal for the amount of time mentioned, if you take it to the background by adding `&` e.g. `sleep 1&` the next command will be run instantly as the order of execution will not be synchronized in this case.

Comment: Makes sense haha :3

Comment: @MetNL Added some points ..please do review those..

Answer (score 1):

The last command `sleep 1&&` expects to have something else.

If you remove last `&&`, there will be no error.